# Controle the number of core per MPI process (independently for each rank)

Tags: multithreading, mpi, slurm

I know how to assign a given number of core per MPI processes in a homogeneous way. Meaning N MPI processes with each of them have M cores allocated.

Is there a way to specify the number of core for each MPI processes to get somethink like:

```
rank 0: M_0 cores
rank 1: M_1 cores
rank 3: M_3 cores
...
```

with M to be a vector of N values (N being the number of MPI processes).

Idealy in slurm: So in slurm language: how to set the number of cpus per tasks with a different number of cpu for each tasks.

Comment: Each MPI process will use 1 core unless you are using multi-threading. Are you referring to controlling the number of threads per core, or the number of MPI processes per host?

Comment: One can uses multiple thread on one core :-).
Using OMP_NUM_THREADS will specify the number of cores allocated to the processes, but this number will be the same for each processes. I was wondering how to have different number of cores available for each processes.

Comment: I think I just found the answer at least for OpenMPI:
mpirun -np 1 OMP_NUM_THREADS=M_0 : -np 1 OMP_NUM_THREADS=M_1 : ..... myexec

Comment: Now the question is how to do the same thing with slurm....

Comment: So you are using multi-threading with OpenMP. That's what I was asking. You can use the function [`omp_set_num_threads`](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu110.html) to set the number of threads before the parallel section. it overrides `OMP_NUM_THREADS`. This has nothing to do with MPI or slurm.

Comment: Slurm uses `--cpus-per-task` or `SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK`, but that is homogeneous. It also protects against overallocation (although that may be configured differently on your cluster). So a solution with omp_set_num_threads or OMP_NUM_THREADS might need playing with `--oversubscribe` or `--overcommit`. Maybe you should also tag your question with slurm?

Comment: @aziz as asked in the question, the problem is not the number of thread but the number of cores. And I am not using OpenMP. But the  OMP_NUM_TREADS variable look to do the job with MPI run

Comment: Do you mind sharing your code? I am not sure I understand how you're not using OpenMP when you are using OMP_NUM_THREADS to control the number of cores. This environment variable is part of OMP (OpenMP), not MPI.

Comment: @DavidDaverio Just to clarify, are you referring to how the scheduler assign processes per nodes? (e.g. if you have 2 nodes, 16 cores each, and you want 1 MPI process to have all 16 cores in 1 host, and 2 other MPI processes to have 8 each on the other host). If you could provide more details, and perhaps an example or code, it would be very helpful :)

Comment: @Aziz Yes thats it. The code is not really relevant. Indeed its really how the scheduler assign processes and their affinity. 
Your example : (e.g. if you have 2 nodes, 16 cores each, and you want 1 MPI process to have all 16 cores in 1 host, and 2 other MPI processes to have 8 each on the other host)  is one example.

Comment: @aziz Indeed OMP_NUM_THREADS is really linker to OMP, but it look like that when setting mpirun distribute the processes accordingly and then you end up with a given number of processes per host which leave some cores/cpus unused and then one can assign the affinity of some thread to be using them.

Comment: I see. I am not sure if you can do that directly with the scheduler, but you can use the hostfile to control how many processes are assigned to each host, and therefore assign different MPI processes to each host.